# My preloader animation appears every time when i click anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, preloader

My preloader animation appears every time when i click anything. I want it to appear for single time when entering the website or just for home page.

```
<div class="loader"><div style="width=150%; height=150%; background-color:white;" id="bodymovin"></div> </div>
```

I used jquery to delay the loading time to show the animation properly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
                     $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

I just want it to show once per session when enter into website or just for home page. I need help on this. Thank you.

Comment: we need more code.

Comment: No `click` event appears at code at Question

Comment: it's just when my website loads the animation appears- check it here- https://www.toolitmedia.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `document.referrer` and `document.domain` for discover first entry or no  and add `style="display:none;"` for loader

```
<div class="loader" style="display:none;">
    <div style="width=150%; height=150%; background-color:white; border-style:solid;" id="bodymovin">
       My text for one show...
    </div>
</div>

<a href="">test link for self page(for not show loader)</a>
```

like this:

```
  var referrer =  document.referrer;
  var domain = document.domain;
  if(referrer.indexOf(domain)<0){  //if refer from curent domain. 
     $(".loader").show();          //show loader
     setTimeout(function(){
          $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
     }, 5000);

  }
```

Comment: i tried it but doesn't work. check it here - toolitmedia.com

Comment: Can you post the code here as you said slightly edited

Comment: i tried it several times but it's the same ..when i click anywhere the animation happen again

Answer (score 0):

I think you tell not all.

Your code has listener for click event somewhere else.

Comment: No, i found the specific code to load the animation from https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/

Answer (score 0):

You could check before calling the timeout

```
   if(!$('body').hasClass('loaded')){
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
                         $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 5000);
   }
```

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work. I am seeing on other posts, they talked about cookies.